# Implementing "open all in..." using a bookmarklet

Tags: javascript, bookmarklet

I would like to open a group of urls, one per tab (assume the browser is configured appropriately) using a bookmarklet (this is for mobile browsers, which, as far as I can tell, don't have url subgroupings, and don't support "Open all in...").  The essential bookmarklet code is

```
const sites = ["a", "b", "c"];
sites.forEach(function (v, _) { window.open("http://twitter.com/" + v); }
```

This code doesn't work: it opens the first url in a new tab and does nothing else.  I might have messed up the bookmarklet boilerplate, but if I type the same code in the console, I get the same result (plus, if I change `window.open` to `alert` the bookmarklet works as expected).

I have fiddled around with the second argument to `window.open`, using `"_blank"` (the default, I believe) and `"win" + i` (when the index formal parameter as added to the function delcaration) to no good effect.  Does anyone have any suggestions as to what I can do to make this code work?  Or suggest the proper code to do what I want?  This behavior occurs on Chrome 80.0.3987.149 and Firefox 74.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you’re trying to make a bookmarklet to open three new pages whose addresses are `http://twitter.com/a`, `http://twitter.com/b`, and `http://twitter.com/c`, then you need to:

1. close the parenthesis opened to the left of `function` in your example
2. turn off your pop-up blocker
3. use this string as your bookmarklet’s address and click on it:

```
javascript:const sites = ["a", "b", "c"]; sites.forEach(function (v) { window.open("http://twitter.com/" + v) })
```